# Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Sendgrid doesn't send email in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

UPDATE:
I got it to send emails by actually accessing my app through heroku's website, but it still fails when I run the app from a production server in my cloud9 ide. Is that normal? Is that the way the tutorial wants me to do it?

In chapter 11 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial you are asked to signup for the Sample App in deployment mode with an email you control and check your email account for the account activation email.  I did not receive any emails and the sendgrid add-on for heroku reports that no email requests have been sent. However, in the cloud 9 ide puma server console it reports that the email was sent with the correct format, to the correct address, and I can retrieve the activation token and email address from the console. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully, all the relevant code is included below. Please help.

I actually went to the sample app website and clicked sign-up and then waited for the email. Is this not what Hartl means by "sign-up for a new account in production"?

config/environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

#Sendgrid configurations from their website
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name =>ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password  =>ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain    => 'heroku.com',
  :address   => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port      => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

mailers/application_mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'noreply@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

environments/production.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'gentle-lake-88943.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

users_controller.rb:

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account"
      redirect_to root_url
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

user.rb:

```
 def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
 resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

Comment: do you have an active [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) account?

Comment: I do, yes. It is an "add-on" to the heroku app I am using along with the tutorial for deployment. When I access its dashboard, it says 0 requests for emails.

Comment: Did you put 'SENDGRID_USERNAME' and 'SENDGRID_PASSWORD' to `Heroku` from console (or another way)?

Comment: The tutorial said that SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD are environmental variables automatically set by the sendgrid add-on. I did not explicitly communicate the value of them to Heroku, as I assumed that it was heroku that set their value. I did push the code to Heroku and migrate my database to Heroku, but aside from that no.

Comment: check yourself, inputing from console `heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME` or  `heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD`

Comment: yes, it returns my username and password.

Comment: delete Sendgrid configurations from `config/environment.rb` and try to specify protocol for host in  `environments/production.rb` :  `host = 'https://gentle-lake-88943.herokuapp.com'`

Comment: didn't seem to work.

Comment: Is `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` set in any of your config files? You can also check the current value in the running application in the Rails console using, `Rails.configuration.action_mailer['perform_deliveries']`

Comment: config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true, is set in my configuration, but it still isn't sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this tutorial's problem. My initial problem was i did not write  the variable name correctly. I had reviewed my code and I fixed it. My app works fine now, as tutorial says.

As Igor says at his last answer, you dont need any special code in config/environments.rb so you should erase it if you keep it.

Check your environment's variables in Heroku with `heroku run printenv`. If those are correct, try the BAD way, just as test: replace `ENV['SENDGRID_xxx']` by your sendgrid's username and password.

[Thanks to Nathan Road](https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-list-all-environment-variables-on-heroku)